# Why does this programme output the wrong value of the string in main?

Tags: c++, string, struct, scope, undefined-behavior

The following code outputs the correct string in the parameters function, but the incorrect string in main.

Obviously something is going wrong, but I can't see what it is. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef struct sim {
    
    const char* dir;

} sim;

string convertToString(char* a)
{
    string s(a);
    return s;
}

int parameters(sim *sdata, char **argv, int argc){

    char *filename;
    string token;
    string delimiter = "=";
    size_t pos = 0;
    string s;

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i){

        s = convertToString(argv[i]);

        while ((pos = s.find(delimiter)) != string::npos) {
            token = s.substr(0, pos);
            s.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
        }

        if(token == "-dir"){
            sdata->dir = s.c_str();
            cout << sdata->dir << endl;
        } 

    }

}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    sim * sdata = (sim*)malloc(sizeof(sim));
    
    parameters(sdata, argv, argc);
    
    cout << sdata->dir << endl;
    
    free(sdata);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I started the program with ./teststring -dir=/home/stephen and got:

/home/stephen
�a

I was expecting both outputs to be the same.

Comment: Unrelated: Use `new` and `delete` in c++ wherever possible.

Comment: Tell us: Where does `sdata->dir` point? When does `s` get destroyed?

Comment: Do **not** use `new` and `delete` (and `malloc` and `free`) in C++ *. Use `std::make_shared` and `std::make_unique` when needed.

Comment: You don't need to do the `typedef struct { ... } name;` dance in C++. That's a C thing. `struct name { ... };` works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The program has undefined behavior.

The pointer `sdata->dir` will be invalid after exiting the function `parameters` because the object `s` will not be alive. It has only the block scope of the function.

Also use the operators `new` and `delete` instead of calling the C function `malloc`. So write

```
sim * sdata = new sim;
```

You could write within the function for example like

```
    if ( token == "-dir" )
    {
        sdata->dir = new char[s.length() + 1 ];
        strcpy( sdata->dir, s.c_str() );
        cout << sdata->dir << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        sdata->dir = nullptr;
    }
```

provided that the data member `dir` is declared without the qualifier `const`.

```
typedef struct sim {
    
    char* dir;

} sim;
```

Also using the `typedef` specifier in the structure declaration is redundant in C++.

So in main you will need to write

```
delete [] sdata->dir;
delete sdata;
```

Comment: Or better, just use `string` instead of `const char*` in the `struct`